# How to enable moving text in TextInput to the left, if there is not enough space in the TextInput field

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput field, this field has a limited space, so I want to make text move to the left, so left character would be hidden, but user would be able to see, what he is currently typing, how to do that?

So in this example, I want letter "H" be hidden, and character after "w" should be able to appear on the screen.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually TextInput is left moving. Once input reached the TextInput's bounds(right border here), the text will move left. For your scenario you can just add right padding to get your desired output.

Refer this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/SyKBJOoh-).

Comment: You are right,  I had a problem with TextInput width after I fixed it, it starts work! Thanks!